# G++4.9 not found, Raspberry Pi Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt, gcc

I am trying to install gcc4.9 and g++4.9 on my raspberry pi jessie.

I am following [this tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/), however when it comes to running:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++4.9`

I get:

```
Reading Package Lists..Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information.. Done
E: Unable to locate package g++4.9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++4.9'
```

My sources.list is as follows:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free
```

I get the feeling I just need to another source in this list to be able to install it.  But how can I find a source that hosts it, and is compatible with my Raspberry Pi Jessie?

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in your command. It should be:

`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.  I just typed it fast in here.  That is the command I was running.

Comment: If you use Raspbian jessie you should have already installed gcc in version 4.9. To check this type: `gcc -v`

Comment: Oh! If it's already installed how come it's not in the repo?

Comment: It is. You are just making mistakes. it's `gcc-4.9` and `g++-4.9`.